# Azure AD B2C Set Authentication Contact Info Email Address

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to programmatically update the Authentication Contact Info email address for a contact created using Azure AD B2C.

[image]

I have attempted to do this via the Microsoft Graph and Azure AD Graph API, but failed in both cases each time. For example;

```
PATCH /{tenantId}/users/{userId}?api-version=1.6 HTTP/1.1
{
       "givenName": "James12344",
       "mail": "james@wood.com"
}

Which results in:

{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Property 'mail' is read-only and cannot be set."
        },
        "requestId": "b4f626a1-022f-439a-90b2-a76d1e31d823",
        "date": "2019-02-13T16:43:55"
    }
}
```

How can I programmatically set this field?

Comment: Azure AD Graph [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/25386)

Comment: Micorsoft Graph [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4019)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, the Alternate Email field only from the "Authentication contact info" section using the **Azure AD Graph API**, and Only Authentication contact info: **Alternate email** could be modified via the Azure AD Graph at this time. For this reason, you could find the gap between AAD Graph API and MS Graph API [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/).

**User Authentication Contact Info**

```
PATCH https://graph.windows.net/<b2ctenant_id>/users/<user_id>?api-version=1.6

{
  "otherMails": [
    "<Alternate Email>"
  ]
}
```

The Authentication contact info: **Email** field is only editable via the portal at this time.